# Magento's API not working properly on Nginx server

Tags: magento, nginx, soap

I have three Magento website with multisite setups and hosted on Nginx server. there is only one admin panel and a front domain is different for all the three sites.

So, My issues are below:

- Using Magento's API I am calling SOAP request to my website and try to update the product information, but the Nginx server returns the 302. Below I provide more details:
- Using POSTMAN software, I am calling the API call on the server, at that time product's information's are updated successfully but server gives response 302 Moved Temporarily.

Below, I have provided screenshots:

[image: sceenshot]

Also, when I am calling the same API to my local server (local machine), it will give me 200 ok statuses. This issues occurring on my Nginx server only.

if you have any suggestion or ideas for resolving my problem so please provide us.

Thank You,